# How do I disable a portion of Twitter Bootstrap responsive design using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm currently building a Ruby on Rails app and I am using the `twitter-bootstrap-rails gem` and have started making heavy modifications to the responsive layout using `@media` css calls. However, to maintain a specific type of formatting, I'd like to disable the `large desktop @media (min-width 1200px)`. I understand how to do this via the normal Twitter Bootstrap process, but would prefer to maintain the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

If something could please direct me on which file to add to my `assets/stylesheets` or how to modify the `@ call`, I'd greatly appreciate it!

I'm looking to find the cleanest way to do this so when I upgrade the gem it doesn't impact the other files. Thanks!

Comment: what about overriding these in your boostrap_and_overrides.css file? was one generated for you when installing bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your layout will be enclosed in a container-fluid and that you have some final level css for site specific styling.

How about putting this in your lowest level css

```
/*
* container
*/
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Set the max width to the maximum size you want and dont bother hacking about with bootstrap.